# Yii2 default filter state for grid view

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

This is one I feel really daft for having to ask about but I'm simply not getting my head around it. I'm building a web application for managing volunteers at a community festival (& it's my own volunteer commitment). The application has `Application` (as in job application) & `Commitment` models, which both have a `year` attribute that is defined in the database as `year(4)`, so having no month or day information. I have corresponding `ApplicationSearch` model, `ApplicationController`, `CommitmentSearch` model, & `CommitmentController` which are currently just as generated by Gii, as are the views.

In my application backend, the default state of the `GridView` on `ActionIndex` for both of those models the should be to display only records for the current year.

Comment: Really difficult to help you without models structure and info about how this gridview is built.

Comment: It's currently all as Generated by Gii, including the views on both models.

Comment: Well, yes... But we don't know what is the structure of the database tables. Like for example - `year`. Is it something like `2017` or more like `2017-08-03`?

Comment: The year attribute is defined in the database as `year(4)`, so is like `2017`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is enough but in the `*Search` models set your `year` fields to `date('Y')` and make sure `year` is added in `rules()` and there is something like `$query->andFilterWhere(['year' => $this->year])` in the `search()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way is based on assigning the actual  year to your dataProvider

```
 public function actionYourAction()
  {
      $searchModel = new YourModelSearch(); 

      $queryParams = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;

      $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($queryParams);
      if (!isset($queryParams['YourModelSearch']['your_year_column']))      {
         $dataProvider->query->
              andWhere('your_year_column =  YEAR(curdate())'  );

      }

      ......
```

Comment: That did it, as did setting `$searchModel->year = date('Y');` based on Bizley's comment above. Thanks to you both.

Comment: This is wrong. With this query condition you can not filter gridview for different year than current.

Comment: default state != fixed state

Comment: @Bizley  correct  ..  answer  updated  ..checking  if the value for the year  is not set